# How to take find the value attached to a specific index of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have to return the value for a specific index of an array.

I am to take the last digit in my array and use that digit as the index for where to look in my array. Meaning if my array is 6543743 I need to return the value at the 3rd index, which should be 4. I have this so far, but it keeps returning 3 - it's taking the final index instead of going to that index for the value.

```
            x = array[array.length-1];
```

I'm clearly missing something, but I can't figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: array is zero index so length -1 means last element. if you want element before loast you should call length -2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subset the array *twice*:

```
int[] array = { 6 5 4 3 7 4 3 };
int num = array[array[array.length - 1]];
```

The last value in the array is given by `array[array.length - 1]`, and then this value is used as an index again into the same array.